# Which database design for complex quiz app?

Tags: mysql, database-design

at the moment I am designing a database (mysql) schema for a complex quiz app. I am at the question stage at the moment, and struggle a little with the table design. Here's what I got so far:

question

```
task

id  type        etc.
1   mpc
2   text-input
3   matching
4   fill-gaps

task_to_question

task_id     question_id
1           10
2           20
3           30
3           31
3           32
4           40

answer_set ->(task_to_question)

id  question_id answer_id   correct
1   10          100         1
2   10          101         0
3   10          102         0
4   10          103         0
5   20          100         1
6   20          200         1
7   30          100        (1)
8   31          300        (1)
9   32          301        (1)
10  40          100         1
11  40          400         1
12  40          401         1


addon

answer_set_id   gap_number
10               1
11               1  
12               2
```

The idea is that the task-table has just some basic info and the type-field which decides how to handle the task.
All tasks are in the same table; every task has one or more questions (task_to_question), depending on the type, e.g. mpc has one question, but a task where you have to match questions and answers has 4 questions. In the same vein, every question can have multiple answers (answer_set) - especially important for one or two-word text-input. So even within a task type, the number of questions and answers is fluid. This can of course be restricted later, as well as subtypes added.
The last table is only joined when the task type cannot be handled by the simple field types. In this example, I need to define the order of gaps in a "fill in the gaps in the text" task. This could be one addon-table, or even multiple tables for distinct task types (to reduce overhead)

My intention for this was to reuse as many text-strings as possible. So I can have the same question-text and the same answer-strings for mpc, input, fill-the-gap, and partly even matching tasks. Similarly, I think it will be easy to collect suggestions for autocomplete fields, without having to sort through duplicates.

But the more think about it, the more I think it is actually too convulted. Problems I already see are e.g. that I already have some redundancy when a question has only right or no answers - correct column becomes redundant. And my answers must be varchar, even if I might add other question types. And then I may have to join more tables when I have vastly different task types anyway, so why not use separate tables from the beginning? This is basically how it's done in Ilias. Is it even a big advantage in getting rid of the tables for every type? Then again, I will only have task model that has to have all the handlers for all the task types, instead of separate models.

Wow that was a lot of text ... well, I needed to write it down to see it in full. Still not quite sure how to handle it. input gladly appreciated!

edit: Another thing ... is it just me, or is it kinda weird that the answer_set table references question_id? Is that the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for general suggestions are thoughts rather than a specific answer, so I'll give you some of mine.

Consider the need for the many-to-many between tasks and questions carefully. There are a few concerns I'd have with this approach:
* When you want to edit a question in the context of a specific task, that may inadvertently make the question invalid for another task.
* Might it be possible to have the answers differ between questions based on context (the task)?
* The added overhead of a many-to-many may be a wash with the re-use of strings.

I don't know enough about your need for sub-typing the tables, so I can't really speak to that.